# Scala: Implicit evidence that BigDecimal is Numeric

Tags: scala, implicit

How does `scala.math.BigDecimal` is implicitly converted to `scala.math.Numeric`?

*For example*: for `Int` chain of implicit conversion is traced like: `Int` to  `RichInt` (conversion defined in `Predef`) and method

```
protected implicit def num: Numeric[T]
```

from parent class `scala.runtime.ScalaNumberProxy`.

The tricky part with `scala.math.BigDecimal` is that it does not have any wrappers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Numeric[T]` is a type class, so it doesn't convert the `BigDecimal` to a `Numeric`; instead, there is an implicit `Numeric[BigDecimal]` defined which contains the implementation of `Numeric` which operates on `BigDecimal` values.

The implicit is defined here - https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.12.x/src/library/scala/math/Numeric.scala#L187

Comment: How does this implicit appears to be in `Predef`? I do not need to import anything from `scala.math` for this implicit to work. Please elaborate.

Comment: Good question. The implicit instance exists in the companion object for Numeric, which is one of the places scala looks for implicit values. It will check the companion for the implicit type (Numeric) and its type parameters (BigDecimal), and the current scope. You'll want to read up on where scala looks for implicits to better understand this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5598085/where-does-scala-look-for-implicits

Comment: As such, when defining your own implicits (or better yet, type class instances) try to keep them in the associated companion object.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it makes total sense :)